# Trying to decrypt code using time-of-decryption

Tags: c, encryption

I learned a while back, that there is a possibilty to decrpyt a code using the following method, if the code-verification loop looks something like this:

```
char *code, *user_input;         /* assume the pointers are pointing valid data */
while(*code++ == *user_input++); /* go over char by char */
printf((*p == '\n' && q == code + strlen(code)) ? "ok\n" : "fail\n");
```

If this is the code-verification loop, then I can supply inputs, and check how much time does it take the loop to return *fail*. If it took X clock cycles, I was right at the 1st char, 2X - at the 2nd also, and so on...

The way to hide the data inffered from this type of loop was to add a delay, limit user-inputs (can't brute-force), or iterate over the whole loop anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char * code = "1234";
    char *user_input;
    size_t len = 16;

    while(getline(&user_input,&len, stdin))
    {
        char *p = user_input, *q = code;
        clock_t start = clock();

        while(*p == *q){p++, q++;};
        printf((*p == '\n' && q == code + strlen(code)) ? "ok\n" : "fail\n");
        clock_t end = clock();      
        printf("%d\nTry again!\n", (int)(end - start));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this how the primitive decryptors work like?

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack

Comment: Thanks!! I looked for it but coudln't remember how it is called

Comment: I don't think the resolution of `clock` is high enough for this. Try `rdtsc` instead (or an equivalent instruction for your CPU).

Comment: From my tests it was indeed insufficient (couldn't see difference between `"1111" `and `"1222"`) but this is the general idea, I think, and that is basically my question